# How to create API methods in Google App Engine that have several decedents/ancestors

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am having trouble understanding how to structure an ancestor tree with several decedents. Suppose I have a model like this (every Entity has a `Long id`):

```
User
    -Post
        -Comment
```

Where the `Comment` is the grandchild of the `User`.

What is really annoying is to insert a `Comment` I need to generate the Key of the `Post`. And to generate the Key of the `Post` I also need to know the ID of the `User`:

```
Key<Post> postKey = Key.create(Key.create(User.class, userId), Post.class, postId);
```

This is a problem for me because when trying to insert a Comment into the datastore I need to also pass in the userId and postId just to generate the key of the `Post`.

Similarly, it is annoying to try and get a one Post because I need to pass in both the userId and postId to generate the Key.

**I am looking for a better way to structure my model and API methods without having to pass in all those ancestor IDs to my methods**. I was considering storing the websafeKey in every Post and Comment entity as a property like this:

```
String websafeKey = Key.create(Key.create(User.class, userId), Post.class, postId).getString();
Key<Post> key = Key.create(websafeKey);
```

Then I could the key to every Post and Comment (and other children of these Entities)) right there in the Entity. Then presumably I wouldn't have to pass in all those ancestor IDs in to my API methods all the time.

Not sure if that is a good idea though.

Comment: This is though to answer, since you don't say what consistency level you require. The relationship between `User` and `Post` does not necessarily have to be an ancestor one. It should suffice if the `Post` contains a `@Index Ref<User>`. A couple of seconds eventual consistency really shouldn't matter since nobody can comment on a post that is not there yet.

Comment: I suppose you are correct there. This database is for a mobile app so that is why I am trying to pass around simple things like `Long` IDs and `String` websafeKeys. By having `@Index Ref<User>` I could then make a query with a filter on that user object and get all posts from a user right?

Comment: Yup, and if you already have the id of `Post` you don't need the ancestor anymore.

Comment: Just a couple of interesting reads for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484588/the-5-writes-per-second-for-an-entity-group https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the info provided you have two options:

- Pass full keys around and design your API around that
- decouple your entities ancestor relationships, so that no entity has a parent

Note: after writing this all out, I realized the end API looks the same really either way:

```
GET /user/{key} - get user info
POST /user/{key}/post/ - create post 
GET /post/{key} - get post
POST /post/{key}/comment/ - create comment
GET /comment/{key}
```

#### Full keys

In this case, {key} is the websafe key.

Advantages:

- you can maintain transactional and consistency control
- allows you to change parent entity relationship later without migrating old data and breaking old links (in my experience this is a massive win)
- Allows you to mix kinds (e.g. Have a Post kind and a Post2 kind, or an ImagePost kind - useful for polymorphism or for breaking migrations)

#### Decouple entities as ancestors

In this case {key} is the id, and there is no entity hierarchy

Dis/Advantages:

- Simplicity
- You need to infer the kind based on the URL
- listing posts for a user or comments for a post would always be eventual
- no migration path if you need to introduce transaction groups

Overall benefits of structuring your API like this:

- internal coupling for consistency and transactionality not exposed through API
- aligns with restful API as resource concept
- supports either model

In my experience you should absolutely do the first option, you will probably get your data model wrong a few times, and being able to change/migrate it is an absolute win.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I agree with Konqi when he says that you should carefully design your ancestor/keys model
to get the right level of consistency that you want, taking in consideration the trade-offs of write/sec 
throughput.

Assuming that you still want the user -> post -> comment design, to deal with datastore ancestor 
key references like this, we came to a solution that is almost similar
to your idea. We create string representations of the keys. For your specific case,
it would be:

```
/users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
```

We also have a convenience type to encapsulate that representation, called `IdRef<T>`.

Everytime an Entity is retrieved from the datastore store we construct this representation
and for every API request we translate it from the given string.

Using that approach, we can easily expose APIs like that:

```
GET /users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
POST /users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
DELETE /users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}
```

I maintain an [opensource project](http://yawp.io) that, among other features, solves the problem you are mentioning.
It is a Java DSL designed to expose RESTful APIs from your appengine datastore models.

If you are interested, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/feroult/bd65f5c1b1d4b7f76bdd) that exemplifies your use case.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this answers the question. As i understood it, the op was asking for a way to avoid handleing all those ids by reducing the model complexity (see the bold print in the question). You're basically suggesting that everything is great and oh hey, here's my api wrapper around your database entities for that. While i find your project pretty cool i somehow doubt that it can circumvent the 1 write per second and entity group limitation since that's datastore specific and not specifc to the wrapping api. If it does though, let me know...

Comment: I've agreed with you that he should carefully design its ancestor/key hierarchy based on his necessity of strong consistency. That means to take in consideration the trade-offs you are mentioning. Then, assuming that he still wants to design his Key hierarchy as user -> post -> comment, I think that the solution I've pointed in my API can give him some hints on how  to easily manipulate the Key hierarchy creation/handling as API arguments. What do you think? If this is too self-promoting I may remove the answer...

Comment: You know in the end, it's all up to the op, who am i to judge. It does come on too strong for my taste, though. Maybe leave all the good description parts, remove the javascript parts and say something like "and i have that awesome project here that does all that out of the box and even gives you a JS client here ...  " at the end (make sure your affiliation is clear). The focus should be more on the technical solution.

Comment: @konqi {at}feroult I appreciate anyone taking the time to write an answer on SO, but yeah I am looking for a more technical solution. I think konqi's comments to my post helped a lot.

Comment: @konqi and MicroR, thanks for the feedbacks, I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact problem, and have currently implemented something similar to @feroult, though I am still looking for a better method.   Let me explain some of the logic behind this decision.

Let's assume we read a list of some resource that is at least a few levels down in the tree.  The "comment" example above could be one example.  In this case, if we were to use datastore keys on the client side, then yes, our API would be very RESTful in that the key itself would encompass the path to the root entity.  The problem however is that this method is inefficient since the ancestor path is repeated in every key.

The alternative is to create a tree like structure on the client that resembles the tree like data from the datastore. If we want all the comments made by a user, then we only need to have the user id reside in memory once.  There is no reason to have it represented in a key for every comment.  Which then leads us to the ugly mess of sending the full ancestor path /users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId} in the RESTful api.

At the end of the day, no matter how the actually path looks, the same information must be passed to the datastore.  This is critical.  Google Datastore cannot find a comment without the ancestor path.

This means that the problem can be reduced to one of semantics.  Perhaps the compromise is to create an equivalent client side key factory that can generate a key from the ancestor ids and then send it to the server.  In this case, repetition would be avoided AND the RESTful API would still be clean.

Would be interested in hearing other thoughts.